# How to auto change iframe src value when media query changes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

let query = window.matchMedia("(max-width:1224px)");
let iframe = document.querySelector("main>iframe");

if (query.matches) {
iframe.setAttribute("src", "/HTML/card.html");
} else {
iframe.setAttribute("src", "/HTML/about.html");
}
});
```

I want the iframe  to load a different html page when media query is at max-width:1224px. When I resize the browser it switches to the target page only on refresh or reload. How do we make it switch content as soon as media size changes?

Comment: CSS isn't capable to navigate. The idea of media queries is that you don't need multiple pages for the same content in different sizes. What is the actual issue you're trying to resolve with media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event listener when the viewport resizes, so basically run your logic once on page load (**DOMContentLoaded**) and then again on each resize:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  function changeIFrameContent() {
    let query = window.matchMedia("(max-width:1224px)");
    let iframe = document.querySelector("main>iframe");
    if (query.matches) {
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "/HTML/card.html");
    } else {
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "/HTML/about.html");
    }
  }

  changeIFrameContent();
  window.addEventListener('resize', changeIFrameContent);
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Can't thank you enough man. ( Do you have any channels where I can at least leave a "LIKE".)